# Wierd unwanted painted textures refusing to be deleted

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I started painting the texture of a model I scanned using photos of the scanned man, using stencil brush.
After I finished painting the front face and the left side I started painting the right one, and then everything went wrong- everything got horrifically blue and no matter what I do I cant get the texture blank again, or atleast white!
help! what can I do to start texturing again from the start?
Thanks in advance to all helpers.

[image]

[image: all previouse textures deleted and still this blue thing]

all previous textures are now deleted and nothing is changing

Comment: Well, deleting the texture in the material setup would be a good idea.

Comment: I deleted them all. added a photo of it in the post above. @metaphor_set

Comment: It's hard to tell. Could be a material, could also be something different... Consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and posting the given link in your question (klick "edit")

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The image shows you deleted the texture brush, but not necessarily the texture material. Check those are all deleted or disabled. If you want to start on a blank image again, just add a new image in the UV window.

From your other image it looks like you are adding each image in a separate material which I assume you wish to use for texturing. You should rather have one material where you can add multiple texture slots - those textures once loaded can be used in the texture brushes. Make sure you save your new image and link it back to the new texture in material tab.